# Inconsistent behavior of Quartz2 scheduler in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, cluster-computing, quartz

I have an Apache Camel project that is using Quartz2 as the scheduler. The requirement is to make it a cluster. The code is deployed to weblogic 12c. the quartz is configured as per many samples with clustering enabled.

This is my properties file (without the datasource)

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.JobBuilder.requestRecovery=true

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

When I deploy and start both nodes I see that the `QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE` table has extra entry for one of the nodes:

```
MyScheduler-routerContext   server_node21567108546690
MyScheduler-routerContext-1 server_node11565896495100
MyScheduler-routerContext-1 server_node11567108547295
```

And I am guessing because of that the one node is being called once in a while while the other node gets called all the time (so occasionally both nodes are invoked at the same time).

I have tried to do a clean restart of weblogic nodes but the issue is still there

This is how my route(s) look like:

```
from("quartz2://provRegGroup/createUsersTrigger?cron={{create_users_cron}}&job.name=createUsersJob") 
            .routeId("createUsersRB")
            .log("**** starting check for create users");

//where 
//create_users_cron=0+0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55+*+*+*+?

//expecting one node being called by the scheduler at a time..
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what caused the issue. apparently there were orphan weblogic processes that were running on one (or even both nodes) - this would be a question to our tech archs - why this was such a mess.. ps was showing two weblogic servers running on a node - one that I started recently and one that was there for say a month.. 
expecting this would never happen to production environment I assume the issue has been resolved..